# Fetch data from external json file and set it as global in reactjs app

Tags: reactjs

**My siteurl.json file**

```
{
 "siteUrl": "http://emsplugins.com",
 "imgUrl": "http://emsplugins.com/wp-content/uploads/ovs_images/"
}
```

**I have GlobalConfig.js**

```
import { Component } from "react";

class GlobalConfig extends Component {
state = {};

componentDidMount() {
fetch("/siteurl.json")
  .then((data) => {
    return data.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("data :", data);
    window.siteInfo = {
      site_url: data.siteUrl,
      img_url: data.imgUrl,
    };
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }

  render() {
  return null;
 }
}

export default GlobalConfig;
```

**I imported it from App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GlobalConfig from "./GlobalConfig";

class App extends Component {
state = {};

render() {
return (
  <GlobalConfig />
  )
 }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that the global variable window.siteInfo is undefined while other component is loaded in componentDidMount state. The siteurl.json file is in public folder. I need to set the site url in global for the project.
Thanks in advance.